# Function for alert_is_present() and switch_to_alert()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, alert

I have code (python / selenium):

```
    # Alert start
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    self.driver.switch_to_alert().dismiss()
    # Alert end
```

The first row wait for alert in the browser and second row press "Cancel" button to dismiss this window. It works fine. I decided to create 2 functions.

```
    def alertIsPresent(self, timeout=10):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.alert_is_present())

    def alertDismiss(self):
        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert.dismiss()
```

And I call this functions:

```
    PageObject.alertIsPresent()
    PageObject.alertDismiss()
```

The last ")" is underlined because "parameter self unfilled"...
I'm newest in python, can you give me suggestion?

pageObjectClass:

```
class PageObject:

def __init__(self, driver, xpathLocator):
    self.driver = driver
    self.locator = xpathLocator
    self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100)

def waitElementToBePresent(self, timeout=10):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, self.locator)))

def elementIsPresent(self):
    return EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, self.locator))

def alertIsPresent(self, timeout=10):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.alert_is_present())

def alertDismiss(self):
    alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    alert.dismiss()
```

Comment: can you please share pageObject class please?

Comment: add / updated in question.

Comment: Can you try creating object in your other class like `pageObject = PageObject()` and then `pageObject.alertDismiss()`

Comment: If I add this object in my first class, I have some caution: `Parameter 'driver' unfilled 
Parameter 'xpathLocator' unfilled` But I do not use it.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use two functions, `EC.alert_is_present()` will return the alert

```
def alertIsPresent(self, timeout=10):
    return WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.alert_is_present())
```

You also need to call it from class instance, not type

```
PageObject(driver).alertIsPresent().dismiss()
```

Answer (score 1):

You havn't mentioned the version information of the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s [python](/questions/tagged/python) client.

However, as per the the current implementation and [documentation](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to):

```
switch_to

SwitchTo: an object containing all options to switch focus into

Usage: driver.switch_to.alert
```

So, effectively, you need to replace the line:

```
alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
```

With:

```
alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
```

Comment: hm... If I remove "self" I received message: `Unresolved reference 'self' `

Comment: @Igor-Potapov No confusion about `self`, I missed the `driver`, corrected it. let me know the status